# How to play .opus audio file in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, whatsapp, opus

In my xcode project ,i have to play an audio file from web.The Audio URL is .opus extension.I couldnot play it with native AVPlayer.So somebody please suggest a better way to play audio files of type "opus".

Whatsapp saving voice notes in .opus audio format.

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC can. YOu can download it from here:

http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/iOS/

Comment: Thanks.I did it via cocoapods

Comment: how, can you share some code? I need to play 8kbps opus file with stream of `| Packet size #1 (1Byte) | OPUS data #1 (1～255Byte) | Packet size #2 (1Byte) | OPUS data #2 (1～255Byte) | ... | ... |`

Comment: Please @Hassan, open your own question with more details on hat you need to achieve.